# Ruby - How to subtract numbers of two files and save the result in one of them on a specified position?

Tags: ruby, file, file-io, append

I have 2 txt files with different strings and numbers in them splitted with ;

Now I need to subtract the 
((number on position 2 in file1) - (number on position 25 in file2)) = result
Now I want to replace the (number on position 2 in file1) with the result.
I tried my code below but it only appends the number in the end of the file and its not the result of the calculation which got appended.

```
def calc
    f1 = File.open("./file1.txt", File::RDWR)
    f2 = File.open("./file2.txt", File::RDWR)
    f1.flock(File::LOCK_EX)
    f2.flock(File::LOCK_EX)

    f1.each.zip(f2.each).each do |line, line2|

    bg = line.split(";").compact.collect(&:strip)
    bd = line2.split(";").compact.collect(&:strip)

    n = bd[2].to_i - bg[25].to_i
    f2.print bd[2] << n
    #puts "#{n}" Only for testing
    end

    f1.flock(File::LOCK_UN)
    f2.flock(File::LOCK_UN)
    f1.close && f2.close
end
```

Comment: No i only do this as a hobby for myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
lines1 = File.readlines('file1.txt').map(&:to_i)
lines2 = File.readlines('file2.txt').map(&:to_i)

result = lines1.zip(lines2).map do |value1, value2| value1 - value2 }

File.write('file1.txt', result.join(?\n))
```

This code load all files in memory, then calculate result and write it to first file.

FYI: If you want to use your code just save result to other file (i.e. `result.txt`) and at the end copy it to original file.